# Regular expressions with beautiful soup, extracting all letters after ':'

Tags: regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I can't seem to use regular expressions the way I want to.

When I run this code, I get the  text below

```
for paragraph in soup.find_all('p'):
        print(paragraph.find_all(text =re.compile(":*\w*")))
```

The text I get is

`Continuing our series of surfacing 2016 stinkers, here are the 25 Russell 2000 stocks that imploded in 2016. Further down, you'll find the 25 worst stocks excluding pharma.
Ophthotech (NASDAQ:OPHT) -94%
Galena Biopharma (NASDAQ:GALE) -93%
Cempra (NASDAQ:CEMP) -91%
Toaki Pharma (NASDAQ:TKAI) -89%
Anthera Pharma (NASDAQ:ANTH) -86%
Adeptus Health (NYSE:ADPT) -86%
CytRx (NASDAQ:CYTR) -86%
Novavax (NASDAQ:NVAX) -85%`

Of which just want to extract stock tickers so the ideal output is:

```
OPHT
GALE
CEMP
TKAI
```

and so forth.

I tried variations of these codes:

```
for paragraph in soup.find_all('p'):
    print(paragraph.find_all(text =re.compile('(:\w+)')))
for paragraph in soup.find_all('p'):
    print(paragraph.find_all(text =re.compile("(:*\w*)")))
for paragraph in soup.find_all('p'):
    print(paragraph.find_all(text =re.compile('(:)?\w+')))
```

but most of the time I'm ending up with an output of

```
`['Continuing our ', 'series', " of surfacing 2016 stinkers, here are the 25 Russell 2000 stocks that imploded in 2016. Further down, you'll find the 25 worst stocks excluding pharma."]
['Ophthotech (NASDAQ:', 'OPHT', ') -94%']
['Galena Biopharma (NASDAQ:', 'GALE', ') -93%']
['Cempra (NASDAQ:', 'CEMP', ') -91%']
['Toaki Pharma (NASDAQ:', 'TKAI', ') -89%']
['Anthera Pharma (NASDAQ:', 'ANTH', ') -86%']
['Adeptus Health (NYSE:', 'ADPT', ') -86%']
['CytRx (NASDAQ:', 'CYTR', ') -86%']
['Novavax (NASDAQ:', 'NVAX', ') -85%']`
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: What does the original text that you are trying to parse look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this :

```
import re

text = """Continuing our series of surfacing 2016 stinkers, here are the 25 Russell 2000 stocks that imploded in 2016. Further down, you'll find the 25 worst stocks excluding pharma.
Ophthotech (NASDAQ:OPHT) -94%
Galena Biopharma (NASDAQ:GALE) -93%
Cempra (NASDAQ:CEMP) -91%
Toaki Pharma (NASDAQ:TKAI) -89%
Anthera Pharma (NASDAQ:ANTH) -86%
Adeptus Health (NYSE:ADPT) -86%
CytRx (NASDAQ:CYTR) -86%
Novavax (NASDAQ:NVAX) -85%"""

#Its better to compile a regex outside a loop
pattern = re.compile(r':(\w+)\)')

results = pattern.findall(text)

for items in results:
    print(items)
```

Comment: I still have to use a loop to obtain the text from soup.find_all('p'), but this code seems to work. `for paragraph in soup.find_all('p'):
 print (pattern.findall(paragraph.text))`.   I still don't understand why the `r` needs to be placed in front of the regular expression. Thank you.

Comment: The prefix `r` means "raw string". Without it, you should double escape the metacharacters. For example, `r"\d+"` is equivalent to `"\\d+"`

Answer (score 1):

This might be good direction

```
re.search(r':(\w+)\)', paragraph.text).group(1)
```

Try adding r'' before pattern

Comment: Thanks. Using playing around with your suggestion, I came up with this cde

`for paragraph in soup.find_all('p'):
 re.search(r':(\w+)\)', paragraph.text)`

I'm getting the following output (which seems correct), but not sure how to print it

`<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(18, 24), match=':OPHT)'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(24, 30), match=':GALE)'>`

Comment: Yes, you are right, see updated unswer. In short .group(1) will give you desired string